# Create Custom Product attribute in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9

I want one custom DateTime attribute to filter product data. So can anyone suggest how to create an attribute for the site?

Comment: where you want to attribute share screenshot

Comment: I want https://prnt.sc/n7d8rm this field using datetime picker

Comment: you want to datepicker attribute create programatically or admin side create?

Comment: Yes right i want datepicker attribute for product.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Open the calendar.js (Path js/calendar/calendar.js) and find the below code

```
if (this.showsTime) {
```

Replace with

```
if (this.showsTime=true) {
```

and also update `this.showsTime = true;` in line 40

Step 2. Open the file in the following location lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Date.php

You see below code line 177

```
$displayFormat = Varien_Date::convertZendToStrFtime($outputFormat, true, (bool)$this->getTime());
```

Replace with

```
$this->_escape($this->getValue('M/d/yy H:mm')); //  The Format given is zend_date format
$displayFormat = Varien_Date::convertZendToStrFtime('M/d/yy H:mm', true, true);
```

And also add function above the getElementHtml() function.

```
public function getTime()
{
    return true;
}

public function getFormat()
{
    return 'dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss';
}
```

Now move core file to local and update into below files

app/code/local/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Backend/Datetime.php

in this file you see formatDate($date) function You see below code line 86

```
$date = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date($date,
           Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT),
           null, false
        );

        Replace with below code

        $date = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date($date,
          Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT),
          null, false
       );
```

Do all changes as per this; update me if you have any issue after that.